# Accidentally removed the List View web part from the Reusable Content popup - How can I restore it?

Tags: 2007, reusable, web-part, ghosting

I was working on a project to provide Up Button functionality for the list view web part, and ran across this functionality in the Reusable Content popup. I opened reflector and set to work to reverse the engineer the code for use on any list view.

While doing so I created an error on the Reusable Content page (I believe it is called ReusableContentPicker.aspx but I am away from my VM and can't check.) and deleted the list view web part that was displaying the Reusable Content list from the page in web part maintenance mode. Not enough coffee that morning (>_<)

Now when I load the page I just see the heading about adding Reusable Content but no list.

Any ideas on how to get the list back on the page?

Would an unghost from code work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I'm aware the reusable content picker page is called ReusableTextPicker.aspx and lives in the /Layouts folder.

Having a look at this file, there is no list view web part, but instead the list of reusable content is rendered using an SPGridView.

Is it possible that you edited the file directly on the filesystem? I can't see how you may have removed the grid any other way.

Comment: I did open the file in SPDesigner but I did not make any changes and I believe it was still working after I checked it back in. I am just now able to access my VM and I will check that possibility. When I have more rep I will upvote your answer.